# find the missing values from a set of values, using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, in-clause

How can I find a missing values from a set of values, using SQL (Oracle DB)
e.g.

```
SELECT NAME
FROM ACCOUNT
WHERE ACCOUNT.NAME IN ('FORD','HYUNDAI','TOYOTA','BMW'...)
```

(The "IN" clause may contain hundreds of values)
If 'HYUNDAI' is missing in the ACCOUNT table, I need to get the result as "HYUNDAI".

Currently I use the result of the above query to do a Vlookup against the original set of values to find the missing values, I want to directly get the missing values without doing the Vlookup.

Thanks
Kiran,

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got it reversed. Do this: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09239/3

```
SELECT Brand
FROM 
(
    -- Oracle can't make a row without a table, need to use DUAL dummy table
    select 'FORD' as Brand from dual union
    select 'HYUNDAI' from dual union
    select 'TOYOTA' fom dual union
    select 'BMW' from dual      
) x
where Brand not in (select BrandName from account)
```

Sample Account data:

```
create table account(AccountId int, BrandName varchar(10));

insert into account(AccountId, BrandName) values
(1,'FORD'),
(2,'TOYOTA'),
(3,'BMW');
```

Output:

```
|   BRAND |
-----------
| HYUNDAI |
```

---

Better yet, materialized the brands to a table:

```
select *
from Brand
where BrandName not in (select BrandName from account)
```

Output:

```
| BRANDNAME |
-------------
|   HYUNDAI |
```

Sample data and live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09239/1

```
CREATE TABLE Brand
    (`BrandName` varchar(7));

INSERT INTO Brand
    (`BrandName`)
VALUES
    ('FORD'),
    ('HYUNDAI'),
    ('TOYOTA'),
    ('BMW');


create table account(AccountId int, BrandName varchar(10));

insert into account(AccountId, BrandName) values
(1,'FORD'),
(2,'TOYOTA'),
(3,'BMW');
```

Comment: I think, this will work but, will be tedious to type the query if there are hundreds of values.(but can Use Excel). Any other options?

Comment: I dont have access to create table, that is why this is tricky

Comment: If you can't create table, just use `UNION` on subquery(see the answer above), or if you are using MySQL,Postgresql,Sql Server you can use `VALUES` shortcut

Comment: if you use CTE as in my answer you have no need to use create table

Comment: @Luxspes CTE is not the only answer. If the OP uses MySQL, CTE can't be used, a simple table-deriving query would suffice then

Comment: never said it was the **only** answer

Comment: I did not know about sqlfiddle.com, this will be very useful. Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
SELECT a.val
FROM
(
    SELECT 'FORD' val    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'HYUNDAI'     UNION ALL
    SELECT 'TOYOTA'      UNION ALL
    SELECT 'BMW'         UNION ALL
    etc...
    etc...
) a
LEFT JOIN account b ON a.val = b.name
WHERE b.name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly, thanks Michael.

```
SELECT Brand
FROM 
(    -- Oracle can't make a row without a table, need to use DUAL dummy table
    select 'FORD' as Brand from dual union
    select 'HYUNDAI' from dual union
    select 'TOYOTA' fom dual union
    select 'BMW' from dual      
)
where Brand not in (select BrandName from account)
```

Luxspes and Zane thank you for your inputs

Answer (score -1):

You should use [Except](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx): EXCEPT returns any distinct values from the left query that are not also found on the right query.

```
WITH SomeRows(datacol) --It will look for missing stuff here
AS( SELECT *
    FROM (  VALUES  ('FORD'),
                    ('TOYOTA'), 
                    ('BMW') 
                    ) AS F (datacol)),
AllRows (datacol) --This has everthing
AS( SELECT *
    FROM (  VALUES  ('FORD'),
                    ('HYUNDAI'),
                    ('TOYOTA'), 
                    ('BMW') 
                    ) AS F (datacol))
SELECT datacol
FROM AllRows 
EXCEPT 
SELECT datacol 
FROM SomeRows
```

Comment: "Not In" will give me values other than the once I have queried for but which are in the table.

Comment: Yes, "not in"  was not the answer, I have changed my answer, please use [EXCEPT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx).

Comment: I will not know which is the missing element, HYUNDAI was just a example.

Comment: I know, I just only used HYUNDAI because you used that in your example, my code will find everthing that is in AllRows table but it is not in SomeRows table

Comment: Removed the "HYUNDAI" stuff from the Source table to avoid confusion

Comment: But how will I know which value to leave in SomeRows?

Comment: You do not need to know  which value to leave out in SomeRows, SomeRows is an example, in real life, that would be a table with unknown missing values

Answer (score -1):

Contributing Excel code to make the typing of the answer easier:

Say column A has the values (Ford, Hyundai,...).

In column B, put this in every cell:

```
select 'x' as brand from dual union
```

In column C, write this formula, and copy it down.

`=REPLACE(A2,9,1,A1)`

All of the  `select`/`union` statements should appear in column C.