# how does a SQL query (Pro*C) be able to find set of values that are not present in a db table

Tags: sql, database, oracle, list

I have a C/C++ program with embedded Oracle SQL calls in pro*c (11.2+ version). I have a list of values (int) as an array. I would like to check through a SQL query (as pro*c code) which values are not in a DB table. For example, say, I have values: `10, 20, 30, 40, 50` stored in an array and my DB table t1 has column col1 that has `10, 20, 40`. So,

```
Select col1 from t1
```

will provide me:

```
10
20
40
```

So, I am looking for  the excluded values, i.e. 30, 50.
Can I do this through an embedded Pro*C SQL query?
My list is quite large and the DB table has many values.

Comment: Where's the list of values coming from?  If they were in the database it'd be trivial to return your desired result.

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: I'm using Oracle, and I will write the code as embedded SQL in Pro*C for Oracle, I have an array of numbers in my C/C++ code, that I would like to check non-present in an Oracle DB table

Comment: possible duplicate of [find the missing values from a set of values, using SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464543/find-the-missing-values-from-a-set-of-values-using-sql)

Answer (score 4):

You need to set up your values in a table.  Here is a typical way what will work in most databases:

```
with list as (
      select 10 as n union all select 20 union all select 30 union all
      select 40 union all select 50
     )
select l.*
from list l
where not exists (select 1 from t1 where col1 = l.n);
```

The syntax might vary depending on the database (`from dual`, a subquery instead of a CTE), but the idea is the same.

Comment: This is cool. But, my list is quite large, I have the list of values as a C/++ array and I am trying to write an embedded SQL in Pro*C for Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle you could use a collection as an alternative to creating a CTE/inline view using unioned queries:

```
select l.column_value as missing
from table(sys.odcinumberlist(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)) l
where not exists (select 1 from t1 where col1 = l.column_value);

   MISSING
----------
        20
        30
        50
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/082395/1).

Here `sys.odcinumberlist` is [a built-in collection type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/ext_types_ref.htm#ADDCI4964), to save you creating your own table type.

Aside from being slightly easier to type the values in like that (IMO), you can also use this approach from a client application by passing the values as an array, which can be useful. There are examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18675238/266304) for OCI (C/C++) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21034016/266304) for Java.

Comment: can I use the array of C/C++ that contain values, there are many values to check, and the DB table has also many values

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT regexp_substr('10|20|30|40|50', '[^|]+', 1, ROWNUM) var
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length(regexp_replace('10|20|30|40|50', '[^|]', '')) + 1
MINUS
SELECT col1 FROM t1;
```

Comment: my list is quite large, from within C/C++ code, this will be huge to do a '10|20|... '