# SQL:How to dynamically return error code for records which doesn't exist in table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to replicate a workplace scenario. The sqlfiddle for Oracle db is not working so I couldn't recreate the table.

Say I have a table like below

```
Table1
+----+------+
| ID | Col1 |
+----+------+
|  1 | A    |
|  2 | B    |
|  3 | C    |
+----+------+
```

Now we run a query with `where` condition. The `in` clause for `where` is passed by user and run time and can change.
Suppose user inputs `1,2,4,5`

So the SQL will be like

```
select t.* from Table1 t where t.id in (1,2,4,5);
```

The result of this query will be

```
+----+------+
| ID | Col1 |
+----+------+
|  1 | A    |
|  2 | B    |
+----+------+
```

Now output I am expecting should be something like below

```
+----+---------+------+
| ID | ErrCode | Col1 |
+----+---------+------+
|  1 |       0 | A    |
|  2 |       0 | B    |
|  4 |     404 |      |
|  5 |     404 |      |
+----+---------+------+
```

As `3` was not entered by user, we will not return it. But for `4` and `5`, there is no record in our table, so I want to create another dummy column which will contain error code. The data columns should be null.

It is not mandatory that the user input should go to `in` clause. We can use it anywhere in the query.

I am thinking of some way of splitting the input `id` and use them as rows. Then use them to do `left join` with `Table1` to find the records which exists and doesn't exist in `Table1` and use `case` on that to decide among `0` or `404` as error code.

Appreciate any other way we can do it by query.

Comment: I would also split your id's into rows and then you will be able to use relational operations like joins, etc. Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/splitting-string-into-multiple-rows-in-oracle

Comment: Where are the values coming from - can you create a collection from them? With fixed values this is simple but how you'll really call it may affect the best solution. (You might be able to do something similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31948594/266304) for example)

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35743456/5234334) works perfectly. Thanks for taking time to check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it goes

```
SQL> WITH table_filter AS
  2   (SELECT regexp_substr(txt, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) id
  3      FROM (SELECT '1,2,4,5' AS txt FROM dual)  -- User input here
  4    CONNECT BY regexp_substr(txt, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL),
  5  table1 AS -- Sample data
  6   (SELECT 1 id,
  7           'A' col1
  8      FROM dual
  9    UNION ALL
 10    SELECT 2,
 11           'B'
 12      FROM dual
 13    UNION ALL
 14    SELECT 3,
 15           'C'
 16      FROM dual)
 17  SELECT f.id,
 18         CASE
 19             WHEN t.id IS NULL THEN
 20              404
 21             ELSE
 22              0
 23         END AS err_code,
 24         t.col1
 25    FROM table_filter f
 26    LEFT OUTER JOIN table1 t
 27      ON t.id = f.id;

ID                             ERR_CODE COL1
---------------------------- ---------- ----
1                                     0 A
2                                     0 B
5                                   404 
4                                   404 

SQL>
```

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I want. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 ( id, col1 ) AS
SELECT 1, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT i.COLUMN_VALUE AS id,
       NVL2( t.col1, 0, 404 ) AS ErrCode,
       t.col1
FROM   TABLE( SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST( 1, 2, 4, 5 ) ) i
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       Table1 t
       ON ( i.COLUMN_VALUE = t.id );
```

**Output**:

```
ID ERRCODE COL1
-- ------- ----
 1       0 A
 2       0 B
 4     404
 5     404
```

The collection of ids can be built dynamically using PL/SQL or an external language and then passed as a bind variable. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34699771/1509264) for an example.

Comment: This works fine too. But when I used it on our table with many rows, its cost is significantly higher then the @San's query. 

But thanks for the input. It is definitely lot "neater" than using `regex`. Also thanks for giving a differently example. It would come very handy if you want to split input values to rows.